# Symfony - perist multiple entities

Tags: php, forms, api, foreach, entity

I want to persist my default entity values through one defined variable. I connected some tables trough foreign keys and they already return values that are in the db. As they are fields that can't be changed I just need to pass it in the new row in the db.

```
 public function ticketAddAction(Request $request, $id)

$ticket = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Tickets')->find($id);

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('play', EntityType::class, array(
            'disabled'=> true,
            'data' => $ticket->getPlay(),
            'class' => Plays::class,
            'choice_label' => 'playName',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']
        ))
        ->add('theater', EntityType::class, array(
            'disabled'=> true,
            'data' => $ticket->getTheater(),
            'class' => Theater::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']
        ))
        ->add('hall', EntityType::class, array(
            'disabled'=> true,
            'data' => $ticket->getHall(),
            'class' => Halls::class,
            'choice_label' => 'hallName',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']
        ))
->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $data = $form->getData();

        $this->container->get('tickets')->addNewTicket($ticket);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('published');
    }

    return $this->render('@FrontTemplates/pages/ticket.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'purchase' => $ticket,
    ));
}
```

In this api call everything seems to work fine but in the api call below I cant figure out how to loop trough all this objects by using just one variable..

Here is my service api call..

```
 public function addNewTicket(Tickets $ticket)
{
    $newTicket = new Tickets();

    foreach ($ticket as $newTicket) {
             $ticket->setPlay($play);


               $ticket->setTheater($theater);
                 $ticket->setHall($hall);
    }
            return $newTicket 
}
```

And my entity info

```
    /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Base\Entity\Plays")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="play_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $play;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Base\Entity\Theater")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="theater_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $theater;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Base\Entity\Halls")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="hall_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $hall;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your entity names should be singular to avoid confusion just like this.

In your first piece of code, that form seems to be useless. You do nothing with the "$data" variable. If you want to link that form to your ticket object, you should call the form builder like this: $this->createFormBuilder($ticket)

In your second piece of code you try to loop over a single object. Also, the "addNewTicket" code is not needed if you link your form to your entity correctly.

Also, check out the official docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#building-the-form

Here is the complete code for editing a ticket:

```
public function ticketAddAction(Request $request, $id)

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$ticket = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Tickets')->find($id);

$form = $this->createFormBuilder($ticket)
    ->add('play', EntityType::class, array(
        'data' => $ticket->getPlay(),
        'class' => Plays::class,
        'choice_label' => 'playName',
        'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']
    ))
    ->add('theater', EntityType::class, array(
        'data' => $ticket->getTheater(),
        'class' => Theater::class,
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']
    ))
    ->add('hall', EntityType::class, array(
        'data' => $ticket->getHall(),
        'class' => Halls::class,
        'choice_label' => 'hallName',
        'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']
    ))
->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    $em->persist($ticket);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('published');
}

return $this->render('@FrontTemplates/pages/ticket.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'purchase' => $ticket,
));
}`
```

If your relations are not saved with this code, please add your mapping information. Maybe there is something wrong there.

Comment: Just saw that you have 'disabled'=> true on your fields. If a field is disabled it won't be saved.

Comment: How can I set it so it can be seen but not editable?